# Python 2.7.9 Environment - Reads comments as multiple lines - How to stop?

Tags: python, comments, development-environment

This is a simple quality of life question that's driving me crazy.

I tend to write code in Notepad++, then copy/paste over into the python.exe when its time to run part/all of it.

The Python on my old machine had no problem with comments.

I could do things like

```
#The next line adds 2 numbers!
x+y = 5
# See how easy!?
```

But now this Python has a problem with that. That fails.
Because the line after a #comment is assumed to be a continuation of the comment.

[image]

Comment: You should probably find a new way to run your python code too. I suggest writing it in Notepad++ then using the command prompt to run your saved py file like `python myFile.py`

Comment: Your screenshot clearly disproves your theory - comments don't cause syntax errors, **incorrect syntax** does.

Answer (score 0):

that is not at all what the screenshot shows

```
x+y = 5
```

is never a valid statement in python

maybe you just meant

```
print x+y #still gonna get an error since you dont define x or y
```

?

if you want a multiline comment use a docstring

```
"""
the next line does adding
x+y =5
see how easy a multiline comment is
"""
```

Comment: ...maybe it is meant to be `x = y = 5`